#  Search on other fields of content type

Tags: search, nodes

I created a content type called "Automobile" and that has the following fields: "Model," "Manufacturer," and "Year." When I go to "Dashboard > Content > Find Content," the search does not offer me controls to "find all automobiles between the year 1990 and 1995 with the model Caravan."  How do I configure Drupal to allow such queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create a [view](http://www.drupal.org/project/views) if you want this control.    Like this
[image: automobile view]

This will give you a page with the exposed filters you asked for @ www.mysite.com/automobile.

Comment: make 'Exposed form in block: Yes' will create a block of the exposed filter.  You can put this on any page, configure on the structure->block page.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [Search API ranges](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_ranges) module. Here is a quote about it (from its project page):

> ... provides widgets for Search API range queries. Currently includes: jQuery UI min/max slider.